# Copy to redshift fails with an error when using KMS Managed CMK

Tags: java, amazon-redshift, amazon-kms

I am trying to write a java program which encrypts data using KMS key id. I am using the default java code for uploading an object to S3. I am changing the values to be uploaded to S3 to be a records so that I can use load it to redshift.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3EncryptionClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CryptoConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object;

public class testKMSkeyUploadObject {

    private static AmazonS3EncryptionClient encryptionClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
       String bucketName = "***bucket name***"; 
        String objectKey  = "ExampleKMSEncryptedObject";
        String kms_cmk_id = "***AWS KMS customer master key ID***";

        KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider materialProvider = new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(kms_cmk_id);

        encryptionClient = new AmazonS3EncryptionClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider(), materialProvider,
                new CryptoConfiguration().withKmsRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1))
            .withRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));

        // Upload object using the encryption client.
        byte[] plaintext = "xyz,abc,1"
                .getBytes();
        System.out.println("plaintext's length: " + plaintext.length);
        encryptionClient.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey,
                new ByteArrayInputStream(plaintext), new ObjectMetadata()));

     // Download the object.
        S3Object downloadedObject = encryptionClient.getObject(bucketName,
                objectKey);
        byte[] decrypted = IOUtils.toByteArray(downloadedObject
                .getObjectContent());

        // Verify same data.
        Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(plaintext, decrypted));
    }
}
```

I am using Redhsift copy command with below syntax to copy the records to redshift.

```
copy table_name from 's3://bucket-name/KMSEncryptedObject' credentials as
'aws_access_key_id=<access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<secret-access-key>;master_symmetric_key=<master-key>'
```

When run above copy command I am encountering below error:

```
Query execution failed 
Reason: SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Failed writing body (0 != 16) 
Cause: S3 object 'KMSEncyptedObjecr does not have 'x-amz-meta-x-amz-key metadata 
Details: 
----------------
error: Failed writing body (0 != 16) Cause: S3 object 'KMSEncyptedObjeci does not have 'x-amz-meta-x-amz-key metadata
```

Comment: I have ran into the same issue. Do you remember what was the solution, by any chance?

Comment: I guess, I was uploading the s3 object using aws sdk 2, switching the aws sdk version to old version helped.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you don't have to specify the KMS key id when copying the data from S3. Simply, remove the `master_symmetric_key` argument from your credentials string.

Looking at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingKMSEncryption.html you only need the KMS key ID to upload (and of course the IAM user / role needs to have access to this key).